# Conditional split

Tags: parsing, split, stata

I have a string column that resembles a series of key-value objects, kind of like this:

| Index | String column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A:blahblahblah. B: whatever whatever. C: idkidk. |
| 2 | A:blahblah. C: idkidk |
| 3 | B:whatever whatever. C: idkidk |
| 4 | B:whatever whatever. D: randomstuff |

I need to generate new columns, for each specific key, showing its corresponding value. The thing is that a mere split(.) doesn't work, since not all entries have the same keys.

This is basically what I'd like to achieve:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blahblahblah | whatever whatever | idkidk |  |
| blahblah |  | idkidk |  |
|  | whatever whatever | idkidk |  |
|  | whatever whatever |  | randomstuff |

I've been struggling for a while, but nothing seems right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Will the values always be lower case? What if the value for `B:` includes the string `C:` such as `B:files on C: drive` where the key is `B` and the value is `files on C: drive`. Can you with 100% certainty know that will never be the case? If you cant then this is hard

Comment: And also, if the key is not always a single letter, can you guarantee that the value never has a `:`? The details of what a key can be and what the value could contain is key to solving this

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/oebbnj/conditional_parsing/ It's always a good idea to tell people about cross-posting.

Comment: I came up with a solution that only has two conditions on the key/value pairs. Keys may not include spaces and values may not include `:`. So it is quite a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that work as long as no value or key contains a `:` and no keys includes any spaces. I changed one key in your example data to test multi-letter keys.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte Index str68 String_column
1 "A:blahblahblah. non_single_letter_key: whatever whatever. C: idkidk."
2 "A:blahblah. C: idkidk"                           
3 "B:whatever whatever. C: idkidk"                  
4 "B:whatever whatever. D: randomstuff"             
end

* Get the number of rows and loop over them
count 
forvalues row = 1/`r(N)' {
    
    *Get the raw string for this 
    local raw_string = String_column[`row']

    *Get the first key in the raw string (anything before the first :)
    gettoken nextkey raw_string : raw_string , parse(":")
    local raw_string = subinstr("`raw_string'",":","",1) //Remove the parse character ":"
    
    *Loop over the raw_string until it is empty
    while "`raw_string'" != "" {
        
        *Get the key from above or last loop
        local key "`nextkey'"
        
        *For the last pair in the string when raw_string only contains the last value
        if strpos("`raw_string'",":") == 0 {
            local value "`raw_string'"
            local raw_string ""
        }
        
        *Not yet last pair, parse out this value and next key
        else {
            *Get all content until next parse character
            gettoken value_and_nextkey raw_string : raw_string , parse(":")
            local raw_string = subinstr("`raw_string'",":","",1) //Remove the parse character ":"
            
            *Reverse that content and get the first word in the reversed result
            local v_and_nk_reversed = strreverse("`value_and_nextkey'")
            gettoken next_key_reversed value_reversed : v_and_nk_reversed , parse(" ")
            
            *Reverse the value for this pair and next key
            local value   = strreverse("`value_reversed'")
            local nextkey = strreverse("`next_key_reversed'")
        }
        
        *Test if a variable exist for this key, if not create it
        cap confirm variable `key'
        if _rc != 0 {
            gen `key' = "" 
        }
        
        *Add the value for this row in the variable for this key
        replace `key' = "`value'" if _n == `row'
    }
}
```